# Memcached dependency jar not working with maven project and throwing java.lang.ClassNotFound: net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient Exception

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, spymemcached

My Project is in linux environment. I want to add memcached jar dependency jar in my project. So I have added following lines in pom.xml as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Maven).

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spy</id>
      <name>Spy Repository</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>spy</groupId>
        <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Program is successfully built. But whenever I am running the project jar, it throws following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient
        at MemClient.<clinit>(MemClient.java:12)
        at MemClientUser.main(MemClientUser.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 2 more
```

I have tried few solutions as given in following link :
[Java ClassNotFoundException with maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811392/java-classnotfoundexception-with-maven-dependency) , but it didn't fix exception.
How can this exception be resolved?

Comment: Check that maven is actually getting the jar.

Comment: You need to having the dependency on the classpath which is obviously not the case. How did you start the jar file?

Comment: @khmarbaise : using command -> java -jar <Jar name.jar>

Comment: Is what i expected. You need to the dependency spymemcached to your classpath to get it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to run the jar, as Maven does not "incorporate" the dependencies of a module into the jar it is building. Either run the jar with

```
java -jar yourJar.jar -cp pathToTheSpymemcached.jar
```

where you replace `yourJar.jar` and `pathToTheSpymemcached.jar` appropriately or you may have a look at this: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)