# ClassNotFoundException - in jersey servlet with maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jersey

I have a Jersey RESTful service, with a maven dependency on another project of mine.
I've made sure that Maven Dependencies library is present in the Deployment Assembly.

But when starting the servlet and trying to access classes from my dependency project, i get the `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [product-crud-servlet] in context with path [/product-crud] threw exception [A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/reaf/db/dao/Dao
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.reaf.rest.ProductCRUDService
] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.reaf.db.dao.Dao
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at com.reaf.rest.ProductCRUDService.<init>(ProductCRUDService.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:292)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:422)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:621)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried the [following solution - changed dependency scope to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811419/3150928), but it didn't hel.

I've also tried adding my `Dao` class to the REST resources but I still get the same exception.:

```
resourceConfig.register(Dao.class);
```

My Servlet class currently looks like this:

```
public class ProductCRUDService extends MyResourceConfig {

    public ProductCRUDService() {
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        resourceConfig.register(Dao.class); // this class causes the Exception
        System.out.println(com.reaf.db.dao.Dao.class);
    }
}
```

`MyResourceConfig` is just:

```
public class MyResourceConfig {
    public static final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
}
```

**NB**: When running a *JUnit* test case, I can access my classes witout any issue.

Comment: Subject Jersey, your have some other class in stack trace. Please correct it.

Comment: Obviously the jar containing your `Dao` class is not available in the WEB-INF/lib of your web-app. I'm guessing this happens in your IDE, so you should make sure that you have all the necessary tools that integrate Maven with Web-applications. In Eclipse, these are called [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/)