# NoClassDefFoundError + ClassNotFoundException when executed from a JAR

Tags: java, bash, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

My program has an exception when I run as a JAR from bash, but not from IntelliJ. What is going wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at EndUserHandbook.getLinkList(EndUserHandbook.java:53)
        at EndUserHandbook.main(EndUserHandbook.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>end-user-handbook</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**Manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: EndUserHandbook
```

Comment: tell us what is in your dependency tab except pom. Have you added lib jar in your own jar OR in classpath

Comment: @RaviParekh I updated with a complete pom

Answer (score 0):

How did you launch your program? The way to launch a jar file is `java -jar file.jar`. `java file.jar` doesn't work.

Comment: That's exactly how I launched it. ``java -jar file.jar``.

Comment: Can you try to add `<scope>compile</scope>` to your dependencies? According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811392/java-classnotfoundexception-with-maven-dependency), it should work.