# Driver not found mysql java

Tags: java, mysql, driver

i have an problem with my java program i'm trying to connect to an MYSQL database but it says driver not found i've imported mysql-connector-java into the project even with output set so it exports with  the program

the class:

```
package com.CloudyProductions.GCDSS;

import java.sql.*;


public class mysql {

    public static  Connection c;

    static String host = "localhost";
    static String port = "3306";
    static String database = "";
    static String username = "root";
    static String password = "";

    public static void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the mysql-connector to the project via maven and did what you said but now get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Then almost certainly your MySQL driver JAR is not on the classpath when you are running this program.  Please tell us how you are running this code, from an IDE or from the command line.

Comment: i export it and then run it via command prompt because i need it to run it on that way it's going to be an sort of server manager

Comment: i won't work not gonna use it if it isn't working even tried setting up new program and there in maven still doesn't work

Comment: If you use maven you read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811392/java-classnotfoundexception-with-maven-dependency

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your mysql driver jar into the classpath through command line as follows.

```
//for windows
set CLASSPATH=PATH_TO_JAR

//for unix
export CLASSPATH=PATH_TO_JAR
```

Or you can add it during execution of your application directly using `-cp` as,

```
java -cp PATH_TO_JAR your_class_app
```

or `-classpath`

```
java -classpath PATH_TO_JAR your_class_app
```

Comment: i do this java -cp connector.jar -jar GCDSS.jar but gives me te error classnotfound

Comment: have now the problem invalid or corrupt jarfiel

Comment: but i have placed the manifest.mf and export it

Comment: i'm getting te error classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: what do i have to do now

Comment: Your java -cp connector.jar -jar GCDSS.jar will work only if the connector.jar is in the same directory in which your GCDSS.jar is placed. In your case you have to provide the complete path e.g. -cp C:\your_dir_path_to_connector.jar and execute.

Comment: still getting the error classnotfoundexception

Comment: what is the version of your jar? I think you are using different jar. You need to use latest connector. Try using 5.1.6 of mysql conncetor.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484813/2292766):

> You will have to include driver jar for MySQL MySQL Connector Jar in your classpath.
>
> If you are using command line include the path to the driver jar using the -cp parameter of java.

For example:

```
java -cp C:\path\to\connector.jar Main
```

Comment: the commandline can't find the main class

Comment: i export it as an jar file

Comment: You just have to add `-cp C:\path\to\connector.jar` to your current command. Please show me how you run it on the command line.

Comment: java -jar GCDSS.jar

Comment: How about `java -jar GCDSS.jar -cp C:\path\to\connector.jar` then?

Comment: i have now the problem invalid or corrupt jarfile

Comment: so i got it running again get again the error classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: added it now via Maven stil doesn't work

Comment: @CloudyProductions Which driver did you download? Which platform are you on? What does your command look like now?

Comment: command is java -cp connector2.jar -jar GCDSS.jar i'm using windows and for database xampp mysql

Comment: driver is use now is mysq;-connector-java-5.1.47-bin

Comment: the crazy thing is i did this erlier with an spigot plugin it worked without the connector there

Comment: @CloudyProductions Is the error message stillt `classnotfoundexception`?